# Nativescript Tabview is not rendered at all but there is no exception/error either

Tags: nativescript

In my HTML file I have this markup: While the ActionBar shows the title , the tabviews in the stacklayout are not visible at all and I get no errors, but I do not understand why??? I am new to nativescript... ;-)

Anyone can see what I do wrong?

```
<ActionBar title="Working days planner" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar> 

<StackLayout class="page">
    <TabView id="tabViewContainer">
        <TabViewItem title="First Tab">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label text="Working days" class="action-label m-15"></Label>
                <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
                    <ng-template let-item="item">
                        <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
                    </ng-template>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </TabViewItem>
        <TabViewItem title="Second Tab">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label text="Second Tab" textWrap="true" class="m-15 h2 text-left" color="blue"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView>
</StackLayout>
```

The StackLayout code in the first TabViewItem does work when its put under the ActionBar, but the TabView component somehow screws everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that syntax with the TabViewItem element. Try starting from a simpler example from the documentation page:

[NativeScript TabView for Angular](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view)

Once you get a basic example working take incremental steps to change the content over to yours. Also, this is a basic feature so you can set up a Playground example and share that if you have specific problems.

Comment: ok it seemed I copy/pasted the markup from nativescript page. Your link is for angular@nativescript. So I can not use nativescript elements directly ???

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `StackLayout` above, you really don't need it.

Comment: I removed all StackLayout`s that did not help :/ AND I need that StackLayout to group the Label and ListView component vertically ELSE the ListView is rendered OVER the Label.

Comment: Are you using Angular or Core NS?

Comment: I use angular within NS :F